# Akka - Share a large file in chunks from client to nodes

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I have a relatively large amount of Akka nodes, coded in Scala, in different clusters, communicating remotely, and a central ClusterClient that is used initially.
My goal is to share a large file (multiple GB's) from the Client's filesystem to all the different nodes, by giving each node a subset of the file (not the entire file).

What is the right Akka concept to use for this? Akka's Distributed Data explicitely states that it is not to be used for big data, plus it seems to copy the entire file to the node instead of just a chunk. It seems like Akka's Streams IO is the way to go, but I can't find any example online achieving this goal.

Thanks !

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I'm building a distributed training system, where basically different nodes will treat different data sets. The goal is to get this different data from a main client to a the different nodes.

Comment: ^ have you evaluated other solutions than akka for this specific use case?

Comment: Well, the thing is I will use Akka afterwards to communicate between nodes. That's why I wanted to take advantage that I was already in communication through Akka !

Comment: there are many alternatives to how to distribute the data while still in akka world. just one example, you could upload the file to small chunks in memcached/redis/etc., and have each chunk-actor get it's own partition from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "large file" can be read using the [streaming `FileIO`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-io.html#streaming-file-io) functionality:

```
val file = Paths.get("example.csv")

val fileSource : Source[ByteString, Future[IOResult]] = FileIO.fromPath(file)
```

This source can then be parsed to create "subsets of the file".  The question isn't specific on how the subsets are created, so lets assume that we want to send `256` lines to each node.  [`Framing`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/stream/scaladsl/Framing$.html) can be used to do the parsing and [`grouped`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/grouped.html) will create the chunks:

```
val separator = ByteString("\n")

val maxLineLength = 1024

val chunkSize = 256

val lineParser : Flow[ByteString, ByteString, _] = 
  Framing
    .delimiter(separator, maximumFrameLength = maxLineLength, allowTruncation= false)
    .grouped(chunkSize)
```

These chunks can then be dispatched to the remote nodes.  The question was not specific on how to communicate with the nodes so a stub function is used:

```
val sendChunk : Seq[ByteString] => Unit = ???

val chunkSink : Sink[Seq[ByteString], _] =
  Sink[Seq[ByteString]].foreach(sendChunk)

fileSource
  .via(lineParser)
  .to(chunkSink)
  .run()
```